# PeopleSoft HCM92 ad hoc salary change approval

Tags: configuration, fluid-layout, peoplesoft

I'm new to PeopleSoft in general. I'm trying to set up configuration to allow managers to approve an ad hoc salary change. The problem is this:

Review Transactions Page
[image]

I click there and it brings me to this page...

Error Page
[image]

If anyone has any insight please let me know!